# How to insert multiple rows in one line of insert at cassandra cql?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have following table called 'devices':

userid | deviceid | devicedata | userdata

All columns are varchars and userid+deviceid is the primary key.

Inserting one row in to table seems working:

```
INSERT INTO devices (userid, deviceid, devicedata, userdata)
VALUES ('user7', 'deviceid1', 'devicedata7', 'userdata1');
```

But following doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO devices (userid, deviceid, devicedata, userdata) 
VALUES (('user8', 'deviceid1', 'devicedata8', 'userdata1'), 
        ('user9', 'deviceid1', 'devicedata9', 'userdata1'));
```

I the get following error:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]
  message="Unmatched column names/values"
```

How can I insert multiple rows with one line of INSERT? Is it possible? I know that there is batching option.

Comment: does cassandra support multiple insert rows like mysql?

Comment: No, you have to use batches. See answer of Chris Lohfink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make two requests or unlogged batch if you really need to, but I would recommend just making 2 different async requests, theres little to negative effects in batching them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems batches are the way to go. But I would like to know very much: Is it even possible to insert multiple rows with one line of insert? This is possible at least with T-SQL and mySQL.

Comment: yes, both logged and unlogged. unlogged means you just put both in a single request to be treated separately, logged provides some atomicity at cost of being much more expensive. I would recommend not doing it as it increases load on coordinator when that can be distributed across the cluster as multiple requests instead. I guess important question is _why_ do you want to do multiple inserts in one?